# Usage nuxt composition api and nuxt appollo module

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api, vue-apollo

Why I can use nuxt apollo module with nuxt composition API? If I try use this plugin example:

```
import {Context} from '@nuxt/types'
import {
  provide,
  onGlobalSetup,
  defineNuxtPlugin
} from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
import {DefaultApolloClient} from '@vue/apollo-composable/dist'

/**
 * This plugin will connect @nuxt/apollojs with @vue/apollo-composable
 */

export default defineNuxtPlugin(({app}: Context): void => {
  onGlobalSetup(() => {
    provide(DefaultApolloClient, app.apolloProvider?.defaultClient)
  })
})
```

I get this `Error: Apollo client with id default not found. Use provideApolloClient() if you are outside of a component setup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install vue/apollo-composable:
   `npm install --save @vue/apollo-composable`
2. Create nuxt plugin(provide-apollo-client.ts):

```
import { Context } from '@nuxt/types'
import {
  onGlobalSetup,
  defineNuxtPlugin
} from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
// @ts-ignore
import { provideApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable'

/**
 * This plugin will connect @nuxt/apollojs with @vue/apollo-composable
 */

export default defineNuxtPlugin(({ app }: Context): void => {
  onGlobalSetup(() => {
    provideApolloClient(app.apolloProvider?.defaultClient)
  })
})
```